# Snackbar error message within if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

I have an if statement that errors out if a user selects a file format that is not valid, however, it is currently done within js as an alert, I would like to change this to Material UI's `snackbar` error message. However I am having trouble doing so, the code below.

```
let file = document.getElementById("file-upload");
const onSelectFile = e => {
  setFieldValue(e.target.name, e.target.files[0]);
  setFieldTouched(e.target.name, true, false);
  let fileName = file.value;
  if (
    fileRestrict.findIndex(item => fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(item)) >= 0
  ) {
    //TODO
  } else {
    {
      LongTextSnackbar;
    }
    file.value = "";
  }
};

function LongTextSnackbar() {
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <SnackbarContent
        className={classes.snackbar}
        message={"error error error"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried to imitate Mat UI's `snackbar, but to no avail, inside the else, I need to call another component of material UI's somehow, any suggestions on how I could do this?

Comment: Where do you have this snackbar in your code?

Comment: Do you have any library of components? Are you implementing your own snack bar?

Comment: Took it out as for right now its breaking everything, was more so just looking for an example?

Comment: Are using React material ?

Comment: updated the code to reflect

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check this library https://www.polonel.com/snackbar/

Usage is simple like this:

```js
Snackbar.show({text: 'Example notification text.'});
```

Comment: updated my code to reflect what I have been attempting with the snackbar

Answer (score 0):

Patch this into your code-

Set initial state of snackbar to closed:

```
state = { 
    snackOpen: false 
}
```

Logic to open the snackbar by setting state:

```
  let file = document.getElementById('file-upload');
  const onSelectFile = e => {
    setFieldValue(e.target.name, e.target.files[0]);
    setFieldTouched(e.target.name, true, false);
    let fileName = file.value;
    if (
      fileRestrict.findIndex(item => fileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(item)) >= 0
    ) {
    } else {
      this.setState({ snackOpen: "You have tried to upload an unsupported file type. Allowed file types are ${fileRestrict}"})
      file.value = '';
    }
  };
```

Need to render the snackbar as shown:

```
render() { 
 return ( 
<Snackbar message={this.state.snackOpen} close={() => this.setState({ snackOpen: false })} /> 
)
}
```

**Note:**

1. I have not tested this, just plugged a snackbar in to demonstrate
   how it needs to be done.
2. The material-ui Dialog component is more appropriate for this use case.

Comment: Cant quite get this to work, Im using react hooks and not quite sure what your doing with the render/

Comment: Looks like you are using a functional component. Forget the render & pulg the snackbar line into the  div in your return statement.
Also it is not very clear which component library you are using, my answer is for material-ui